# How to get from class all the interfaces it inherits (using roslyn)?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a class `Letters` that inherits from interface `IA`, and `IA` inherits from interface `IB`. How can I get with roslyn the interfaces `IA` and `IB`? (I have `ClassDeclarationSyntax`)

```cs
public interface IB
{
}
public interface IA : IB
{
}
public class Letters:IA
{
}
```

Comment: You could use `Type.GetInterfaces`, it will retrieve all the interfaces from which the provided type derives.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like,

```
 var interFacesOfLetters = typeof(Letters).GetInterfaces();
            foreach (var x in interFacesOfLetters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
            }
```

Edit #1

for dynamic class name,

```
  var name = "NameSpaceName.Letters";
  var interFacesOfLetters = Type.GetType(name).GetInterfaces();
  foreach (var x in interFacesOfLetters)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. but if I want to write a generic way to get the interfaces from any class, how can I do that?

Comment: Type.GetType(name) return null. what can I do?

Comment: It should not return null if you have provided full and valid name.

Comment: Still happening :(

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are valid only if you're trying to use reflection to access type information.

To use Roslyn you'll have to use the [`SemanticModel`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/SemanticModel.cs,f8e51661446fa281) to get an `INamedTypeSymbol` for your `Letters` class and then use [`.AllInterfaces`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ITypeSymbol.cs,14726631ee5c2e02)

I don't have Roslyn installed but it should be something like:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
public interface IB
{
}
public interface IA : IB
{
}
public class Letters:IA
{
}
");

var Mscorlib = PortableExecutableReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

var myClass = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Last();
var myClassSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(myClass);

var interfaces = myClassSymbol.AllInterfaces;
```